# Get Number from Random String

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to get the whole number of this random.
[image: Image with random numbers]

Finally, I get a Debug.Log () to display my 757 number

Comment: `random1*100 + random2 * 10 + random3` ? Still not quite sure what your question is !

Comment: (Why not just `Random(100, 999)`?)

Answer (score 5):

You need to build up the whole number:

```
Random random = new Random();

int hundred = 100 * random.Next(1, 10);
int ten = 10 * random.Next(0, 10);
int one = random.Next(0, 10);

int result = hundred + ten + one;
```

Lets assume, the first random gives you 7, the second gives you 5 and the third gives you 7 again. you would end up with:

> hundred = 100 * 7 = 700
>
> ten = 10 * 5 = 50
>
> one = 5
>
> result = 700 + 50 + 7 = 757

Then just log result

Comment: I do not need their sum. I want to get that whole number 757, as an int

Comment: This will give you the whole number as an int. I'll update my answer to clarify

Comment: That is exactly what he is doing @George

Comment: @AzarShaikh That wont give him an `int`

Comment: `string result = (hundred + ten + one).ToString()` just enough.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is random 3 digit number. So simply:

```
Random.Range(100, 1000);
```